# Why does Sqlite create a new table that I have not specified within my create_tables.py file

Tags: python, sqlite

So I have a file called create_tables.py with the following code:

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("mydata.db")

cursor = connection.cursor()

create_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username text, password text)"

cursor.execute(create_table)

create_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name text, price real)"
cursor.execute(create_table)

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

When trying to make a GET request via postman I am provided this error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: items
```

But there is a table that has been created called `item_model`.
[image]

I didn't specify the creation of this table. I am wondering why my `items` table is not being created but this `item_model` table was.

Comment: Probably you are accessing different databases. Even the table `users` in the image has different definition than the CREATE statement in your Python code.

Comment: I've made sure I selected the db file in the directory I am currently working in. There are no other db files it could be pointing to. I am using SQLAlchemy in conjunction with Sqlite, I am wondering if SQLAlchemy is changing how my tables are defined.